# Howto output HTML from drupal module the nice way

Tags: html, drupal, templates, drupal-6

this may be basic, but i just started using Drupal (6 btw).

I'm building a module, and got a callback that is supposed to return some html. I could just do something like this:

```
function myModule_myFunction(){
    $r = '';
    $r .= '<h1>'.$variable.'</h1>';
    return $r;
}
```

But I'd rather seperate logic and presentation, and put this in a seperate file, or something. HTML in strings is ugly!

What's the 'drupal' way to do this? **It doesn't have to use the theme system** as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [theme system](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) is the drupal way to do that.

First check if there isn't already a theme function that you can use, there are many that allow to output data as table, lists, images and much more.

If there is not, you need to...

1. Declare a new theme function with [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). Prefix it with your module, something like `yourmodule_something`.
2. Create a theme function (or a template), a theme function must be prefixed theme_, so something like `function theme_yourmodule_something()`.
3. Make sure to clear all caches so that Drupal knows about your theme function.
4. Call the theme function with [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7): `theme('yourmodule_something', $argument1, $argument2)`:

More details can be found on the linked documentation pages.

Answer (score 2):

[hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) is first used to define templates and functions for themed output.

Then, use those templates or theme functions to output any markup, e.g, to call `theme_my_content` or my-content.tpl.php with a couple of parameters, you can call:

`theme('my_content', $param1, $param2);`